# Puedo hacer un <v-if> dentro de un <v-else> en Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Estoy validando 5 hints de un password. La logica es la siguiente: Si todas las validaciones son correctas, los iconos de los hints son de color1, sino de color2. PERO si solo 4 hints son correctos, el hint restante en vez de ser color2, tiene que ser color3.

Mi codigo hasta ahora:

```
<v-icon small v-if="tips[tip]" color='#71227D'>mdi-check-circle</v-icon>
<v-icon small v-else color="error">mdi-close-circle</v-icon>
```

Intente un `<v-if>` dentro del `<v-else>` pero no funciona. Como podria hacer?

Comment: Puedes utilizar v-else-if pero si tus condiciones cambiaran mucho te recomiendo utilizar v-show [Revisa esta informacion](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Comment: Estás complicando demasiado tu vista llenándola de lógica, prueba mover esto a la instancia de vue y manejarlo tal vez por medio de *watchers*

Answer (score 0):

Puedo ver que estas utilizando vuetify, te doy algunos ejemplos utilizando una forma mas entendible para que observes el componente.

Existen un problema y es que `v-if` como como se expresa en la documentación de VUE en [v-if vs v-show](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show), `v-if` tiene costos de alternancia más altos por lo que puede perderse el cambio de un dato si este es comprometido, `v-if` es optimo para la renderización inicial del componente, ya que solo se utilizaría correctamente si este dato no cambiará constantemente. Por lo que seria mas adecuado utilizar `v-show` ya que este solo modifica la propiedad `display` del estilo de la etiqueta. Mas sin embargo parece que estas utilizando un dato de suma importancia, por lo que te invito a manejar esta data a través de watchers como lo dice @BetaM en su comentario, mira los siguientes ejemplos.

***CON V-SHOW:***

```js
Vue.component("v-icon", {
  template: `<div>
    <i :style="{color:color, 'margin-top':'15px'}" :data-feather="type"></i>
    <p>{{color}}</p>
  <div>`,
  props: ["type","color"],
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.color)
    feather.replace()
  }
})

let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tips:0
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/feather-icons/4.28.0/feather.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/feather-icons/4.28.0/feather.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{tips}}</p>
  <button @click="tips--" type="number" v-model="tips">-</button>
  <button @click="tips++" type="number" v-model="tips">+</button>
  <v-icon v-icon small v-show="tips == 0" :color='"blue"' :type="'check-circle'"></v-icon>
  <v-icon small v-show="tips == 1" :color="'red'" :type="'alert-octagon'"></v-icon>
  <v-icon small v-show="tips == 2" :color="'green'" :type="'help-circle'"></v-icon>
</div>
```

***CON WATCHERS:***

```js
Vue.component("v-icon", {
  template: `<div>
    <div :style="{'color':color, 'margin-top':'15px'}" v-html="toSvg"></div>
    <p>{{color}}</p>
  <div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      type: "alert-octagon",
      color: "red"
    }
  },
  props: ["tips"],
  computed: {
  // PROPIEDAD COMPUTADA INDIFERENTE PARA OBTENER EL ICONO FEATHER RENDERIZADO
    toSvg() {
      return feather.toSvg(this.type)
    }
  },
  watch: {
  // MRAMOS LOS CAMBIOS DE LA PROPIEDAD TIPS
    tips(val) {
      // UTILIZAMOS LA LOGICA CONVENIENTE PARA CLASIFICAR FOO...
      val = Number(val)
      switch(val) {
        case 1:
          console.log(val)
          this.color = "blue";
          this.type = "check-circle";
          break;
        case 2:
          this.color = "green";
          this.type = "help-circle";
          break;
         default:
          this.color = "red";
          this.type = "alert-octagon";
          break;
      }
    }
  }
})

let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tips:0
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

img {
  width: 56px;
  height: 48px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: 26px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/feather-icons/4.28.0/feather.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{tips}}</p>
  <button @click="tips--" type="number" v-model="tips">-</button>
  <button @click="tips++" type="number" v-model="tips">+</button>
  <v-icon v-icon :tips="tips"></v-icon>
</div>
```

Básicamente la idea de trabajar con los watchers es que el componente hijo esté sujeto a cambios y se convierta en un componente mas dinámico, esto por supuesto ayuda a la carga y al renderizado, por otro lado la via sencilla es el primer ejemplo.

Un saludo, espero que te haya sido de ayuda.